# How to get difference between two average values in PostgreSQL, where the averages are on a column, and the final table grouped by two columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, average, unpivot

I want to know the difference between two averages of `value`, where each average is filtered by a condition `isCool` to be either `True` or `False`, and the final result grouped by `town` and `season`, e.g.

`table`

```
| id | value | isCool | town   | season |
|----|-------|--------|--------|--------|
| 0  | 1     | True   | TownA  | spring |
| 1  | 2     | False  | TownA  | winter |
| 2  | 3     | True   | TownB  | spring |
| 3  | 4     | False  | TownA  | winter |
| 4  | 5     | False  | TownB  | spring |
| 5  | 6     | True   | TownB  | winter |
```

I want to end up with the table:

```
| category | difference_of_is_cool_averages |
|----------|--------------------------------|
| TownA    | 2                              | <-- ABS(1 - (2 + 4)/2)
| TownB    | 0.5                            | <-- ABS(5 - (3 + 6)/2)
| spring   | 3                              | <-- ABS(5 - (3 + 1)/2)
| winter   | 3                              | <-- ABS(6 - (4 + 2)/2)
```

I have attempted this but my PostgreSQL skills are limited and I did not get far at all, unfortunately. I tried

```
SELECT
   AVG(value), town
   (SELECT id, value, town, season
   FROM table
   WHERE isCool = 'True') AS TableSummary1
GROUP BY town;
```

but this is far from what I want. Is someone able to help please? Is this even possible with PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `Union All` will help you. Simply calculate the difference of average once by grouping `town` then by grouping `season` and union them. You can write your query like below:

```sql
select
town "Category",
round(abs(avg(value) filter (where iscool='t') - avg(value) filter (where iscool='f')),2) "difference_of_is_cool_averages"
from town
group by town

union all

select
season,
round(abs(avg(value) filter (where iscool='t') - avg(value) filter (where iscool='f')),2)
from town
group by season
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=afafbc3bcc31984bddb886ccdabb753f)

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot, and then compute the difference between the two conditional averages of each group:

```
select x.category, 
    abs(avg(t.value) filter(where not t.iscool) - avg(t.value) filter(where t.iscool)) diff
from mytable t
cross join lateral (values (town), (season)) as x(category)
group by x.category
```

If you want to be able to order the resultset as showed in the desired results, then we need to keep track of the original column:

```
select x.category, 
    abs(avg(t.value) filter(where not t.iscool) - avg(t.value) filter(where t.iscool)) diff
from mytable t
cross join lateral (values (town, 1), (season, 2)) as x(category, grp)
group by x.category, x.grp
order by x.grp
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=177857ec5a044a1e5d2094423f045d4c)**:

```
category |                   diff
:------- | ---------------------:
TownB    |     0.5000000000000000
TownA    | 2.00000000000000000000
winter   |     3.0000000000000000
spring   |     3.0000000000000000
```